# Access QObject inherited class from another QObject class

Tags: qt, qml, qobject

I have the following class, set in a `ContextProperty` at the start of the application:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Q_INVOKABLE MyClassModel getModel() const { return m_myClassModel; }
private:
    MyClassModel     m_myClassModel;
}
```

In one of its methods, `MyClass` fills `m_myClassModel` with data (coming from a server).

`MyClassModel` also inherits `QObject` (because of `Q_PROPERTY` macros):

```
class MyClassModel : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT

     // Lots of Q_PROPERTY macros
     Q_PROPERTY(int stuff READ stuff WRITE setStuff NOTIFY stuffChanged)
 public:
     ...
 signals:
     void stuffChanged();
 ...
}
```

Then, in a QML file, `MyClassModel` is used to trigger signals and update graphical elements:

```
Item
{
    anchors.fill: parent

    CustomLabel
    {
        Connections
        {
            target: myClass.myClassModel()
            onStuffChanged: { console.log("signal triggered!") }
        }
    }
}
```

Because of `Q_INVOKABLE MyClassModel getModel() const { return m_myClassModel; }`, I'm getting this error:

```
error: C2248: 'QObject::QObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QObject'
```

I think I understand the cause of this error, but I am not sure about what I should do to prevent it. I need to have access to `MyClassModel` from `MyClass` in order to fill it with data, yet I cannot return it into my `QML` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning `MyClassModel` from `getModel`. This means copying the object. Copying `MyClassModel` involves a call to the implicitly generated copy constructor, which in turn calls copy constructor of base class (`QObject`). But copy constructor of `QObject` is `private`, this is why you get an error. Designers of Qt have decided long time ago that `QObject` should be non-copyable.

Solution is to return a pointer:

```
Q_INVOKABLE MyClassModel* getModel() const { return &m_myClassModel; }
```