# Access an QObject class from another QObject class by reference and parallel using in qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qobject

In an QML-Application I instantiate two classes that inherit QObject and one class needs access to the other class. Also both classes are declared to qml in main.cpp by qmlRegisterType.
When I use code like the following I get an qqmlprivate-error. 
This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462500/access-qobject-inherited-class-from-another-qobject-class) but it's not the same. How can I fix this?
Thank you!

TimeControl.h

```
class TimeControl : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TimeControl(QObject *parent = nullptr);
};
```

MyTimeTable.h

```
class MyTimeTable : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyTimeTable(TimeControl *timeControl, QObject *parent = nullptr);
private:
    TimeControl *m_timeControl = nullptr;
};
```

MyTimeTable.cpp

```
MyTimeTable::MyTimeTable(TimeControl *timeControl, QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    m_timeControl = timeControl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
qmlRegisterType<TimeControl>  ("tld.we.TimeControl", 1, 0, "TimeControl");
qmlRegisterType<MyTimeControl>  ("tld.we.MyTimeTable", 1, 0, "MyTimeTable");
TimeControl *timeControl = new TimeControl();
MyTimeTable timeTable(timeControl);
```

added QML-Code

```
import tld.we.MyTimeTable 1.0

Popup{
MyTimeTable{
    id: timeTable
}

ToolButton{
    text: "Update"
    onClicked:
        timeTable.updateData();
}
```

Comment: Seems like this is a bug: `MyTimeTable timeTable(&timeControl);` Should probably be `MyTimeTable timeTable(timeControl);`? Also, please add the error message you are receiving and any QML you have written to try and access these objects/classes.

Comment: Yes, that's a bug. The error messages result from qqmlprivate.h:
no matching function for call to 'MyTimeTable::MyTimeTable()'     and
use of deleted function 'QQmlPrivate::QQmlElement<MyTimeTable>::QQmlElement()'
Thanks!

Comment: Are those runtime errors from QML or compile time errors? If from QML, please add your QML code to your question.

Comment: If you are going to use qmlRegisterType with MyTimeTable it implies that you are going to create that object in QML so the constructor is not necessarily going to receive TimeControl and that is detected when compiling.

Comment: A possible solution is to implement the timeControl in MyTimeTable as a Q_PROPERTY.